# Sorteio de valores pré-definidos

Tags: c#, random

Tenho dois TextBox (**txtUM**, **txtDois**), e gostaria de realizar um sorteio de algumas data/string pré-programados (Entre as datas: *07:55, 07:56, 07:57, 07:58, 07:59, 08:00, 08:01, 08:02, 08:03, 08:04, 08:05* ).

O número que fosse sorteado colocaria no textbox (**txtUM**), e depois de outro sorteio um outro valor no (**txtDois**). Seria algo como o ***Random***, mas nesse caso já tenho os valores que devem ser sorteados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

coloque as datas dentro de um array e sorteie um inteiro para equivaler ao índice do array.

```
string[] datas = new string[] { "data 1", "data 2", "data n" };
Random r = new Random();

txtUM.Text = datas[r.Next(datas.Length)];
txtDOIS.Text = datas[r.Next(datas.Length)];
```

Comment: É de notar que com esta resposta é possível ser seleccionado o mesmo valor duas vezes.